# Using file_line from puppetlabs_stdlib in module not working

Tags: puppet

I am attempting to use file_line from the Puppetlabs stdlib module, however I am hitting a brick wall. When I try and run my module, I get the following error:

```
2018-01-23 12:34:16,981 ERROR [qtp2056613703-62] [puppetserver] Puppet This expression is invalid. Did you try declaring a 'file_line' resource without a title? at /etc/puppetlabs/code/modules/my_module/manifests/control_1_5_1.pp:5:3 on node puppet-slave-1
2018-01-23 12:34:16,982 ERROR [qtp2056613703-62] [puppetserver] Puppet Server Error: This expression is invalid. Did you try declaring a 'file_line' resource without a title? at /etc/puppetlabs/code/modules/my_module/manifests/control_1_5_1.pp:5:3 on node puppet-slave-1
```

My rspec test brings back a similar error:

```
  1) my_module with default values for all parameters should contain Class[my_module]
 Failure/Error: include stdlib

 Puppet::PreformattedError:
   Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Function Call, Could not find class ::stdlib for puppet.eu-west-1.compute.internal at /etc/puppetlabs/code/modules/my_module/spec/fixtures/modules/my_module/manifests/init.pp:38:3 on node puppet.eu-west-1.compute.internal
```

I am running Puppet 5.3.3 on both server and client, the following info shows when I run a puppet module list:

```
/etc/puppetlabs/code/modules
├── puppetlabs-stdlib (v4.24.0)
└── my_module (v0.1.0)
```

I am including stdlib in the init.pp file for my module.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
Adding a sample block of code. This is how I am attempting to use the stdlib module. For test purposes, this class will be dropped straight into the init.pp file, in production it will be in a seperate .pp and included in init.pp

```
class my_module {
  include stdlib
  file_line { 'sudo_rule':
    path => '/etc/sudoers',
    line => '%sudo ALL=(ALL) ALL',
  }
}
```

Comment: We can't say much about this if you do not present example DSL code (derived from *your* code, not stdlib's) that reproduces the problem.  More specifically, we want to see a [mcve], else you haven't adequately defined the problem.

Comment: Adding the example to the original question

Comment: Hmm.  The error message "Could not find class ::stdlib" strikes me as particularly important, but nothing you've presented explains why such a problem would occur.  Are you sure that `puppet module list` shows the output you present when you run that command *on the server*?  (It doesn't matter whether that or any other module is installed on clients.)

Comment: Hi, thanks for sticking with this John. Yes, this is run on the server.

Comment: What is the name of the stdlib directory on the filesystem?  It appears that it should be `/etc/puppetlabs/code/modules/stdlib`, can you confirm?  (I'm uncertain mainly about the leading path components).

Comment: Hi John. The path you mentioned above is where the module is located

Comment: I had to explicitly provide the modules path using modulePath option in my puppet file apply command in terminal: 

```bash
 puppet apply 0-the_sky_is_the_limit_not.pp --modulepath /etc/puppet/code/modules
```

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this and i was able to fix it by placing the module name in quotes like this

```
include 'stdlib'
```